# make xtick label in multiplication format

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, ticks

Here is what I've got.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    xmax=20,xmin=4,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.6,
    xlabel=\emph{Number},ylabel=\emph{F1 Score},
    xtick={20,16,...,4},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.20,...,0.6},
    x dir=reverse,
    ]
     \addplot+ [mark=pentagon*,mark size=2.5pt,every mark/.append style={}] coordinates{(20, 0.37) (16, 0.33) (12, 0.29) (8, 0.23) (4, 0.21)};
     \addplot coordinates{(20, 0.46) (16, 0.45) (12, 0.45) (8, 0.43) (4, 0.42)};   
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

but I want this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way is to add the labels explicitly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    xmax=20,xmin=4,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.6,
    xlabel=\emph{Number},ylabel=\emph{F1 Score},
    xtick={20,16,...,4},
    xticklabels={$4\cdot5$,$4\cdot4$,$4\cdot3$,$4\cdot2$,$4\cdot1$},
    xticklabel style={yshift=-0.3ex},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.20,...,0.6},
    x dir=reverse,
    ]
     \addplot+ [mark=pentagon*,mark size=2.5pt,every mark/.append style={}] coordinates{(20, 0.37) (16, 0.33) (12, 0.29) (8, 0.23) (4, 0.21)};
     \addplot coordinates{(20, 0.46) (16, 0.45) (12, 0.45) (8, 0.43) (4, 0.42)};   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also redefine `xticklabel` to become `xticklabel={$\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\tick/4}\myx\cdot4$}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \begin{axis}[
    xmax=20,xmin=4,
    ymin=0,ymax=0.6,
    xlabel=\emph{Number},ylabel=\emph{F1 Score},
    xtick={20,16,...,4},
    xticklabel={$\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\tick/4}\myx\cdot4$},
    xticklabel style={yshift=-0.3ex},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.20,...,0.6},
    x dir=reverse,
    ]
     \addplot+ [mark=pentagon*,mark size=2.5pt,every mark/.append style={}] coordinates{(20, 0.37) (16, 0.33) (12, 0.29) (8, 0.23) (4, 0.21)};
     \addplot coordinates{(20, 0.46) (16, 0.45) (12, 0.45) (8, 0.43) (4, 0.42)};   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```